# Find the eigenspaces of the following matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}
        0 & 1  \\
        .25 & 1\\
        \end{bmatrix}$
I have found the eigenvalues $\lambda_1 = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ and $\lambda_2 =\frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ My problem is that i have problems finding the eigenvectors and the eigenspaces of A.

Comment: There are  going to be two eigenspaces since there are two distinct eigenvalues..

Comment: Eigenvectors: $(1,\frac 12 \pm \frac{\sqrt 2}{2})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We would like to find the eigenvalues, eigenvectors and eigenspaces of the matrix $A = \pmatrix{0 & 1 \\ \frac{1}{4} & 1}$. If $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$, then by definition $Av=\lambda v$ for an eigenvalue $\lambda$, so if we identify that $\lambda v = \lambda \mathbb{I}v$ for the identity matrix $\mathbb{I}$ then we can write $(A-\lambda\mathbb{I})v=0$. 
Now we can find the eigenvalues of $A$ by setting the determinant of the matrix $(A-\lambda\mathbb{I})$ to zero. If we do this, then we obtain the eigenvalues $λ_{\pm}=\frac{1}{2}\pm \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$, as you already found.
Now we would like to find the eigenvectors. Let us denote the eigenvectors corresponding to $\lambda_\pm$ by $v_\pm$. We write $v_\pm=\pmatrix{x_\pm \\ y_\pm}$ and we want to find $x_\pm$ and $y_\pm$. What we do is just substitute $\lambda_\pm$ and $v_\pm$ into $(A-\lambda\mathbb{I})v=0$.  Then we find
\begin{align}
\pmatrix{-\lambda_\pm & 1 \\ \frac{1}{4} & 1-\lambda_\pm}\pmatrix{x_\pm \\ y_\pm} = \pmatrix{0\\0}~.
\end{align} 
This gives us two equations. The first one is
\begin{align}
-\lambda_\pm x_\pm + y_\pm = 0~,
\end{align} 
which we can reframe as
\begin{align}
y_\pm = \lambda_\pm x_\pm~.
\end{align} 
The second one is
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{4}x_\pm + (1-\lambda_\pm)y_\pm = 0~,
\end{align} 
and using the previously obtained relation we can write this as
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{4}x_\pm + (1-\lambda_\pm)\lambda_\pm x_\pm = \left( \frac{1}{4} + (1-\lambda_\pm)\lambda_\pm \right) x_\pm = 0~,
\end{align} 
but if we work out the factor between the backets we find that this is always zero. So this equation does not put an extra restriction on our eigenvectors. This means that the eigenvectors are restricted only by the first equation and hence their general form is
\begin{align}
v_\pm = \pmatrix{ x \\ \lambda_\pm x} = \pmatrix{ x \\ \left(\frac{1}{2}\pm \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right) x}
\end{align}
for any real (or complex, if you work in the complex numbers) number $x$. Now the eigenspace belonging to an eigenvalue is just the set of eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue, but as we have already found all eigenvectors, those are now easy to write down. If we denote the eigenspace belonging to $\lambda_\pm$ by $E_\pm$, we have
\begin{align}
E_\pm = \left\{ \pmatrix{ x \\ \left(\frac{1}{2}\pm \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right) x} : x\in \mathbb{R} \,(\,or\, \mathbb{C}\,)\, \right\}~.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

For $\lambda_1$: if $v_1=(a,b)$ is an eigenvector, then $A.v_1=\lambda_1.v_1\to b=\lambda_1a$ and $.25a+b=\lambda_1b \to .25a+\lambda_1a=\lambda_1^2a$ and you can obtain $a$ and $b$. Idem for $\lambda_2$